# update corner radius constraint in dynamically sized cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a custom UICollectionViewLayout that resizes the headers height when scrolling.

Inside the header I have a UIImageView that is constrained to the height of the cell.

I want the image to be round so I set the corner radius accordingly, however it appears when the cell resizes. The constraints hold but the corner radius does not update.

```
let cellImage: UIImageView = {
    let s = UIImageView()
    s.clipsToBounds = true
    s.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    s.image = UIImage(named: "img")
    s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return s
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(cellImage)
    cellImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0).isActive = true
    cellImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75, constant: 0).isActive = true
    cellImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    cellImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = (self.frame.height * 0.75) / 2
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A view's `frame` is not stored directly. It is computed from layer properties `position`, `bounds.size`, `transform`, and `anchorPoint`. What you're seeing here is that the system does not alter the frame using `setFrame:`.

Instead of setting `cornerRadius` in `frame.didSet`, override `layoutSubviews` to set it. The system schedules a call to `layoutSubviews` whenever a view's size changes (and in some other circumstances).

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    cellImage.layer.cornerRadius = (frame.height * 0.75) / 2
}
```